# Call an external dynamic library using node

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, libav, video-editing

I need to edit clips using node using one of the existing video manipulation libraries. (Note: I am aware that I could run an existing editing executable like FFMPEG, but that's not what I am after).

Question: What's the best way to call native libraries in Node?

Background information: I will need to talk to one one these libraries: Gstreamer, FFmpeg/LibAV or libVLC.

My ideal outcome is to have a nice, robust *library* that I use directly using node, but my lack of experience in terms of using native libraries, and the somehow fragmented world of video editing libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [node-ffi](https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi) which helps you call the native C++ libraries in nodejs.